# How to verify Android app calls to Server?

Tags: android, security, server

As we know. the Android apk can be decompiled.  Even if you're using ProGuard, anyone can see your server URLs. I have a basic authenticate scheme on my server where the client passes an AuthToken in the header of a request; if someone manages to steal that AuthToken then they can fool the server.

Which authentication system I should use to prevent this as I have to include something (Key | AuthToken ) in my Java code (app doesn't requires a login).

Comment: Hi Anil. Do you still have questions? I dont see your comments

Answer (score 0):

Here are my pointers on this subject.

APK reverse engineering is doable and your URL is definitely susceptible to attacks. This can be avoided by using token based authentication. Which you are already doing.

How do you think someone can steal auth token? only possibility is to do a network spoofing. This can be avoided using HTTPS.

Also, the token should not be stored anywhere on your device. It should be in memory and every time the user opens the app request for a new token. Since you have mentioned that the app does not need any login, you can provide a short lived auth token or expire the token at server end.

You can also read more on this topic here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: This one: `This can be avoided using HTTPS` is a bit wrong. The proper advice should also include `and use certificate pinning`. Otherwise you still may be MITMed.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thank you very much for the pointers. This is new to me as well